# How to register a custom RangeField in postgre db with django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I tried to follow the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#defining-your-own-range-types) and this is what I came to:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import RangeField
from psycopg.types.range import Range
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class TimeRange(Range):
    """Time interval."""
    pass


class TimeRangeFieldForm(BaseRangeField):
    """Form for time interval."""

    default_error_messages = {'invalid': _('Enter two valid times.')}
    base_field = forms.TimeField
    range_type = TimeRange


class TimeRangeField(RangeField):
    """Time interval field."""

    base_field = models.TimeField
    range_type = TimeRange
    form_field = TimeRangeFieldForm

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'timerange'
```

But there is also that [range_register()](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/pgtypes.html#psycopg.types.range.register_range) thing and I just don't get how to use it in code. And when I try to do migrations I get `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "timerange" does not exist LINE 1: ...IDENTITY, "days" smallint[7] NOT NULL, "interval" timerange ...`. Please help me understand how to create custom range field. Also I don't get how there is DateTimeRangeField and DateRangeField but no TimeRangeField...

Comment: If you can use 3rd-party library, you can use this [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#timeframedmodel) library's `TimeFramedModel`.

Comment: @Hujaakbar there are built-it range field types in django to work with postgre and i need to make my own for time only. so this is not quite what i look for